# How do I use a while with when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, do-while

I have a piece of code where I want it so that it won't execute that piece of code until the necessary button is clicked, in this case a play again button. Here is my piece of code:

```
private void ShowResultsOfThrow()
{
    TwoUp.SetUpCoins();
    TwoUp.ThrowCoins();
    TwoUp.OutputWinner();

    do
    {
       TwoUp.ThrowCoins();
       TwoUp.OutputWinner();
       TwoUp.HoldPoints();
    } while //when the button is clicked to play again

    TwoUp.ResetGlobals();
}
```

Comment: Why put it in a do-while? Put this code in the button_click event...

Comment: It isn't possible for me to do this, is there any other way?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but for that you're going to have to give us a little more background like WHY this can't be done in a button_click, and what exactly you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Blachshma I am trying to make it display in a listbox where I call the ShowResultsOfThrow method but it is just continuously spamming the same message on an endless loop.

Comment: That makes since, as the code is running endlessly in a do-while loop instead of a result of an event. You said you DONT WANT to "execute that piece of code until the necessary button is clicked". Which code are you referring too. What code DO you want to run until the button is clicked and why can't you use the button_click event?

Comment: I need for it to display the setupcoins, throwcoins, output winner into the listbox and then when i hit the button i need for it to display this again. When I setup for it to do it like this it glitched out continously spamming heads, tails over and over again.

Comment: I added an answer, based on your comments. Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just put that code in button_click event

```
private void  button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TwoUp.ThrowCoins();
   TwoUp.OutputWinner();
   TwoUp.HoldPoints();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to make it display in a listbox where I call the ShowResultsOfThrow method but it is just continuously spamming the same message on an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments:

Don't use the `ShowResultsOfThrow()` method. 
Instead, if your button is named Button1, for instance, try this:

```
private void Initalize()
{
     TwoUp.SetUpCoins();

}

private void  Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     TwoUp.ThrowCoins();
     TwoUp.OutputWinner();
     TwoUp.HoldPoints();
     TwoUp.ResetGlobals(); // Optional - not sure what this does...
}
```

Initalize() should only be called ONCE (or whenever you need to setup the coins)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the button.you can do this

let us assume the button name is `btnClick`

let there be a method that would get called when the button is clicked.

```
private void  TwoUpMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TwoUp.ThrowCoins();
     TwoUp.OutputWinner();
     TwoUp.HoldPoints();
     TwoUp.ResetGlobals(); // Optional - not sure what this does...
}
```

Now register this method with the `Click` event of the button.Put this below code in `InitializeComponent()` method of the form

```
btnClick.Click+=TwoUpMethod;
```